# for ( key in array) loops over array prototype

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-chrome

I don't know how to word this problem exactly but I found this extremely wired.

Basically I did this test in chrome's developer tool console.

```
for (var request in [0,1,2]) { console.log(request);}

0
1
2
compare
```

the last four lines are all outputs from the for loop.
during the for loop, request got the value compare.

I wonder if this is a bug in chrome.

Comment: `for..in` is not meant for arrays, use regular `for` loop: `var arr = [1,2,3]; for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++)`.

Comment: this is exactly why you shouldn't use for..in to loop over arrays

Comment: `for .. in` is only for objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`for ... in ...` iterates over the *enumerable properties* of an object, and is not intended for array indices.  Array indices are also enumerable properties, but as you've discovered anything unsafely added to `Array.prototype` will be returned too.

To safely add a (non-enumerable) method to `Array.prototype` in ES5 browsers you can use `Object.defineProperty`, e.g.:

```
Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'compare', {
    value: function() {
        ...
    }
});
```

This will stop `for ... in` from breaking, but it's still the wrong tool for the job when the variable of interest is an array.

Comment: thanks, Just confirmed that compare has been override by other teammember

Comment: @LukaYu do hit him around the head.  Also, one for yourself too, for the `for ... in` loop ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You're best off using an indexed for loop.
For..in also enumerates over inherited properties etc.

```
var request = [0,1,2];
for (var i = 0; i < request.length; i++) {
   console.log(request[i]);
}
```

The top answer to this question:

[stackoverflow previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010840/loop-through-array-in-javascript)

puts it better than I could:

Answer (score 0):

in your case, the global "object-prototype" as a compare function declared for it, e.g...

```
object.prototype.compare = function (a,b) {return a === b}
```

...and so, whenever you iterate an object (an array being one kind of object) you also iterate over the "compare" function of it's prototype... which is a "member" of it.

Answer (score 0):

As others pointed out `for .. in` is not the best way to iterate thru array. If you insist on using it for some reason - use [hasOwnProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) method to determine that property indeed belongs to the array:

```
var arr = [0,1,2];

for (var request in arr ) { 
    if (arr.hasOwnProperty(request)) console.log(request);
}
```